# Linux Join between 2 files

Tags: linux, sorting, join

him I am trying to join two psv files by running:

```
    join -t'|' -1 2 -2 2 <(sort -t '|' -k1 1st_rm_text_from_transactions_22_7_14.plt) 
   <(sort -t'|' -k1 norm_cats_21_07_assignments.psv) > output.csv
```

and I get an error message:

```
    join: file 1 is not in sorted order
```

not sure why I get this error since I do try to sort the files before the join

thanks

Comment: It looks like you are joining them on field 2 ('-1 2', '-2 2') but sorting them by field 1 (`-k1`). Try sorting them both by field 2.

Comment: thanks. Works thanks. Works thanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Worksthanks. Works